# Jenkins in windows container on Windows Server 2016 1607

Tags: windows, docker, jenkins, windows-server

What is the right way to run Jenkins in a windows container on Windows Server 2016 1607. None of the docker images that I pull work, as they appear to be for Linux.

Or am I missing something very obvious?

```
docker info
Containers: 1
 Running: 0
 Paused: 0
 Stopped: 1
Images: 1
Server Version: 18.09.3
Storage Driver: windowsfilter
 Windows:
Logging Driver: json-file
Plugins:
 Volume: local
 Network: ics l2bridge l2tunnel nat null overlay transparent
 Log: awslogs etwlogs fluentd gelf json-file local logentries splunk syslog
Swarm: inactive
Default Isolation: process
Kernel Version: 10.0 14393 (14393.2248.amd64fre.rs1_release.180427-1804)
Operating System: Windows Server 2016 Datacenter Version 1607 (OS Build 14393.2248)
OSType: windows
Architecture: x86_64
CPUs: 2
Total Memory: 8GiB
Name: banubadkrtst
ID: 37Y5:VMWY:THC3:TYZK:27SA:UZFY:3KXN:CT5M:2QYV:PMZX:NTHZ:XIYC
Docker Root Dir: C:\ProgramData\docker
Debug Mode (client): false
Debug Mode (server): false
Registry: https://index.docker.io/v1/
Labels:
Experimental: false
Insecure Registries:
 127.0.0.0/8
Live Restore Enabled: false
```

Thanks

Comment: What is the problem with using `jenkins/jenkins:lts` image ? Do you have an issue with the run command or port mapping ? also what are the log results ? please clarify

Comment: @MostafaHussein: I get the following error:docker pull jenkins/jenkins:lts
lts: Pulling from jenkins/jenkins
image operating system "linux" cannot be used on this platform

Comment: did you guys get the chance to solve it? im having the same problem. my issue is, jenkins/jenkins is built using linux architecture and most of the recommendations i saw on google is to build a new image using windows as base layer then install all the prerequisite of jenkins so i can use it on docker for windows

Answer (score 0):

This seems official:
https://github.com/jenkinsci/docker/blob/master/README.md

Make sure you are using this:
https://hub.docker.com/editions/enterprise/docker-ee-server-windows

Lastly, you are using V1 of the registry. Use V2:
https://docs.docker.com/registry/spec/api/

Comment: My requirement is to have windows powershell based environment for any administration activities inside the container. Also, I would be running multiple other containers which need Windows host

Comment: Modify Dockerfile: https://github.com/matt9ucci/docker-jenkins-powershell

Comment: Also, make sure hyperV is enabled on host. You should be able to run the Linux container on top of Windows.

Comment: PowerShell runs on Linux: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/scripting/install/installing-powershell-core-on-linux?view=powershell-6

Answer (score 0):

According to the following urls:

- [Switch between Windows and Linux containers](https://docs.docker.com/docker-for-windows/#switch-between-windows-and-linux-containers)
- [Running Docker Windows and Linux Containers Simultaneously](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/premier-developer/running-docker-windows-and-linux-containers-simultaneously/)
- [image operating system "linux" cannot be used on this platform](https://github.com/docker/kitematic/issues/2828)

> **Switch between Windows and Linux containers**
>
> From the Docker Desktop for Windows menu, you can toggle which daemon (Linux or Windows) the Docker CLI talks to

You should be able to use the official [jenkins image](https://hub.docker.com/r/jenkins/jenkins/). Make sure to enable the correct mode and try to pull the image again.